# Distinct using objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I am working google and engine and objectify, since for the last 3 hours i have been trying to write a distinct query in objectify. Can anyone tell me how to write a distinct query in objectify on a particular column?

Regards,
Sreekanth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Distinct only works with projection queries, which are not directly supported by Objectify yet. They are on the roadmap. Please star this issue: https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/issues/detail?id=188

In the mean time, you can issue a low-level API query and use objectify's load().fromEntity() to convert the result set to POJOs.

Comment: thank you Mr. stickfigure for the response. Its perfectly working with projection queries.

Answer (score 14):

Objectify (5.0.5+) now supports projection queries and distinct operation.

`ofy().load().type(Entity.class).project("field1").distinct(true);`

Comment: 5.0.3 has [bug](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/issues/detail?id=220), use 5.0.5 instead.

Comment: This must be set as an answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to not that DISTINCT works only with *projection queries* and I don't believe Objectify currently supports them (it currently returns only whole entities).  You can still use the low-level [Datastore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query#setDistinct%28boolean%29) to perform a projection query.

Comment: Did you just copy the answer from stickfigure?

Comment: No Peter, he simply posted his answer at the same time, while I was double checking the docs. I then saw and upvoted his answer but I'm happy to delete this one.

Comment: thank you Mr.tx802 for the response. Its perfectly working with projection queries.