# Projection query with one field distinct and query order based on the other projected field

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have a couple of filters and has projected two fields, i am trying to query distinct ones based on one of the projected field and order based on the other projected field, the projection is working, but i am not getting the distinct values.

code:

```
List <Foo> fooList = ofy().load()
                          .type( Foo.class )
                          .project( "field1" )
                          .distinct(true)
                          .project( "field2" )
                          .order( "field2" )
                          .filter(filters)
                          .limit( 1000 )
                          .list();
```

Answer (score 0):

The question stated is dependent on several factors that need to be considered. This code sample does not give sufficient enough information to answer your question. What type of data set are you using? Are you using the latest Java version? Have the correct packages been imported?

It’s important that you have updated your Objectify version to 5.0.5+ which supports projection queries and distinct operations.
[Distinct using objectify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154817/distinct-using-objectify)

EDIT: In answering your comment

You have imported a file into the Datastore in which you are testing your query. I am referring to the data you are working with and testing your query. How much data are you working with that this issue may be arising? Perhaps you should try using a smaller data set file to test on. The higher the amount of data points you have a higher chance you may run into discrepancies or inconsistencies in your output results.

There are different types of data sets. Are you using structured data? Are you using time-stamped data, which has a concept of time ordering defining that each point was captured or collected? You can be using machine data or big data. You need to consider what type of data you are working. This can be affecting how your data is displayed and recorded through the functionalities that you implemented (in this case the distinct values).

Also what environment are you running your query on?

Comment: yes, I am using the correct version of Objectify (5.1.22) which supports projection queries, java 8 is being used as of now. What do you mean by Data set?